# Maps in App.Fragment and V4.support.fragment

Tags: android, google-maps, android-fragments, android-support-library

I've found many examples about implementing Maps in fragment by using library *support.fragment* but How do we do it with *android.app.Fragment* library.

**Support.fragment**

```
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/mapFragment"
    class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

*Implementation*:

```
public class TrackFragment extends Fragment {
    SupportMapFragment supportMapFragment =
            (SupportMapFragment) getChildFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.mapFragment);
supportMapFragment.getMapAsync(googleMap -> {

     googleMap.setOnMapLoadedCallback(() -> { /* */  }
  }   
 }
```

This is when I import 
`import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;`

if I import `android.app.Fragment` how do I get Map async? How do I load map?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment` shall be replaced by `class="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"`

and

```
SupportMapFragment supportMapFragment =
            (SupportMapFragment) getChildFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.mapFragment);
```

will be by

```
MapFragment supportMapFragment =
            (MapFragment) getChildFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.mapFragment);
```

For more, read out [MapFragment extends Fragment](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/MapFragment)